# Как задать векторную картинку ImageView без подвисаний?

Tags: android

При нажатии на кнопку выполняются действия: старт таймера обратного отсчета и присваивание фото ImageView. И так при каждом нажатии (таймер стартует заново).

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        startCountdownTimer();

        int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(
            flag, "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
        imageView.setImageResource(imageResource);
      }
    });
```

Возникла проблема, когда нажимаешь на кнопку, таймер обратного отсчета стартует мгновенно, а фото присваивается с задержкой (2-3 сек). Вес фото 300 кБ. С фото 2-10 кБ таких проблем нет.

В каком направлении мне нужно решать эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `setImageBitmap` или `setImageDrawable` методы для обновления изображения. `setImageResource` вызывается и выполняется в UI-треде, что приводит к его лагам и различному некорректному поведению